# MySQL / PHP / SugarCRM Scheduling

Tags: php, mysql, sql

And I'm back with new questions. There's probably an easy query to figure out what I need.

I have SugarCRM and I'm using a SOAP WebUI to create meetings on the calendar

Im trying to figure out how I can check to see if the time between meetings.date_start and meetings.date_end is taken already.

Currently I can check if the date I'm entering from the web form is EQUAL to the meetings.date_start with this query:

```
$query="select id, date_start, date_end from meetings where  date_start='$dateToCheck' AND assigned_user_id='$stylist'";
```

where $dateToCheck is in DateTime format

using:

```
$resource=mysql_query($query,$connect)
if(mysql_num_rows($resource)>0)
{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Time is Taken.");';
        echo '</script>';
}
```

I can check that the $dateToCheck = date_start

so for example if i have an appointment that starts at 9:30 am and ends at 10:45
I CANT create an appointment for 9:30 but I CAN for 9:45

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select id, date_start, date_end 
from meetings 
where  date_start<='$dateToCheck' 
    AND date_end>='$dateToCheck' 
    AND assigned_user_id='$stylist'
```

Comment: Not working - now it just allows me to create appointments whenever.

Comment: Entering `select id, date_start, date_end from meetings where  date_start>='2012-05-30 10:15:00' AND date_end<='2012-05-30 10:15:00' ` It returns an empty set - i know for a fact that there is a row with this in it

Comment: @HazyMcGee . Upss... sorry, look at my edited post now. Just reverse operator.

Comment: I used `$query="select * from meetings WHERE '$dateToCheck' BETWEEN date_start AND date_end AND assigned_user_id='$stylist'";`

Comment: @HazyMcGee . +1 Yes, you're right. [It's equivalent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

Comment: Awesome - Im getting the hang of this MySQL stuff :)